# List sheet index beside sheet name in range

Tags: excel, vba, variables, indexing, spreadsheet

I have a list of sheet names in range `H2:H6`
the code I'm using will create the sheets. I need it to also when created to list the sheet index it was assigned to in column G. I get " Variable not defined"

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
On Error GoTo Errorhandling
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("h2:h6")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell <> "" Then
        Sheets.Add.Name = cell
      cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Sheet.Index
    End If
Next cell
Errorhandling:
```

Comment: The proximate cause is that `Sheet` is not defined. You could use `activesheet`. But be careful with the index as it might be the same every time since by default a new sheet is added in front of the active sheet.

Comment: If you know the name of the sheet (you literally just named it `cell`), you can do `Sheets(cell).Index`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know what sheet is in your code. Sheet1 should also be erroring.

Also each new sheet how you have it will be index 1 as they are being created at the front and index is unreliable.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
dim namedsheet as worksheet
On Error GoTo Errorhandling
Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("h2:h6") 'This should be an actual sheet name and not an index probably
For Each cell In rng
    If cell <> "" Then
        set namedsheet = Sheets.Add
        namedsheet.name = cell.value
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = namedSheet.Index
    End If
Next cell
```